# Task chaining (wait for the previous task to completed)

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var guid in guids)
{
    var task = new Task( ...);
    tasks.Add(task);
}

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
    Task.WaitAll(task);
}
```

This is run of the UI thread. I need to execute all tasks in tasks variable one after the other. The problem is if I call Task.WaitAll(task), the UI freeze. How can I do the following logic without having the UI freeze?

Comment: Then why don't you just make one big delegate?

Comment: to add to what @SLaks said, if you just have a list of things to run, using something like BackgroundWorker might be simpler.  The real unknown is what you want to have happen when the background work is done - assuming it's some kind of UI update, BackgroundWorker handles that for you already by running the completed delegate on the UI thread.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is not Task Chaining.

You need to do Task chaining using `ContinueWith`. Last task would need to update the UI.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => DoThis())
   .ContinueWith((t1) => DoThat())
   .ContinueWith((t2) => UpdateUi(), 
       TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

**Note** the last line has `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` this will ensure task will run in the synchronization context (UI Thread).

Answer (score 16):

The best way is to use the **Task Parallel Library (TPL)** and **Continuations**. A continuation not only allows you to create a flow of tasks but also handles your exceptions. This is a [great introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-1-of-n) to the TPL. But to give you some idea...

You can start a TPL task using

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    // Do some work here...
});
```

Now to start a second task when an antecedent task finishes (in error or successfully) you can use the `ContinueWith` method

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Console.WriteLine("Antecedant Task"));
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith(antTask => Console.WriteLine("Continuation..."));
```

So as soon as `task1` completes, fails or is cancelled `task2` 'fires-up' and starts running. Note that if `task1` had completed before reaching the second line of code `task2` would be scheduled to execute immediately. The `antTask` argument passed to the second lambda is a reference to the antecedent task. See [this link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) for more detailed examples...

You can also pass continuations results from the antecedent task

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => 1)
    .ContinueWith(antTask => antTask.Result * 4)
    .ContinueWith(antTask => antTask.Result * 4)
    .ContinueWith(antTask =>Console.WriteLine(antTask.Result * 4)); // Prints 64.
```

Note. Be sure to read up on exception handling in the first link provided as this can lead a newcomer to TPL astray.

One last thing to look at in particular for what you want is child tasks. Child tasks are those which are created as `AttachedToParent`. In this case the continuation will not run until all child tasks have completed

```
TaskCreationOptions atp = TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeMethod() }, atp);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { SomeOtherMethod() }, atp); 
}).ContinueWith( cont => { Console.WriteLine("Finished!") });
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use continutations:

```
lastTask.ContinueWith(() => newTask.Start());
```