# How to handle transaction on two or more methods in which second one depends on first to complete?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am keeping my two methods in a single transaction. Both the methods are working on same tables.

When I keep both in a single transaction, the second one when go to operate on the same tables, it doesn't execute.

I tried to keep both the methods in different transaction , after committing the first one I begin the second one but the same problem occurs.

Then I tried making different objects of session and still the result is same.

I want to keep these methods in transactions . kindly suggest me the suitable way to handle this.
I don't want to make any changes in the stored procedure , I want to handle it on C# code level in my windows application.

Regards,
Nitish

Comment: You could use 2 Tasks and have one wait on the other to complete

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649628/task-chaining-wait-for-the-previous-task-to-completed

Answer (score 0):

Create a Threaded environment. Say Thread 1 is T1 (First Method), Thread 2 is T2(Second Method). Start T1 and T2. But in the T2, Wait for T1 to complete that Pause the T2 and Resume when T1 is completed.

[You can do this easily by using the Transactions at server itself :) ]